# Using Javascript to search through tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

This is my very first post onto Stackoverflow. Happy to be here!
I'm into my 8th week of internship at a company where I'm working on HTML, CSS, Jquery, Ajax, SQL.

Back when I started I was a newbie, but I'm getting the hang of it slowly.

I've run into something I don't know how to solve.

My page displays the tables from a SQL database. It also has a header with the categories.

I've made the searchbar so that I can enter the ID, and it will then display the result live. What I actually want is to be able to search for everything. So Id, client, certname,supplier_id, partner_nr etc.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

Here is my code related to this portion:

**HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="searchTable">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="searchInput" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            </form>
```

**Main.js**

```
$("input[name=searchInput]").on('change keypress paste focus textInput input',function(){
        // Declare variables
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, x;
        input = $(this).val();
        filter = input.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("cfgAccounts");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (x = 0; x < td.length; x++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[x];
                if (td) {
                    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to write such code from scratch on your own? Probably, DataTables is an existing solution to your problem?

Comment: The code I posted inside Main.js got taken of the internet and altered.

Comment: where you want to implement search for backend data or limited to frontend data only whatever you fetch, If its only for frontend , I will suggest go with default DataTables search

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search the whole row then just change the for loop in your code to:

```
// Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i];
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }

        }
```

No need to iterate through each td cell.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work. When I search it does not show the thead and the table striped seems to mess up. The search I get back doesn't keep the striped. So either i get no stripe, or i get stripped depending on the item i search for,

Comment: There was no mention of the thead or stripe. You should open a separate question and post all your code.